# Kong and Postresql running on dockers, pgAdmin cannot connect to database

Tags: postgresql, docker, kong

I have `kong:latest` and `postgres:9.6` running in `containers`.

I can see that `postgres` is running as: `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp`.

I used `network utility` to check `0.0.0.0:5432` and it shows that this port is being used by `postgres`.

I have `dpage/pgadmin4` running as `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp`, I have opened browser with `0.0.0.0:80`, logged in and it works.

Now I try to connect to `postgres` using default `Kong` credentials given during running `postgres` `image` which are:

```
-e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
-e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
-e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong" \
```

so I used `kong` as connect parameters for `pgAdmin` and I get:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What do I do wrong?
Thank you! :-)

Comment: Post your hba_conf from postgres or with what command did you start postgres?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address meaning "everywhere"; it makes sense to listen to that address but not to try to connect to it.  Can you provide your complete Docker setup, either the full set of `docker run` commands you have or your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: docker run -d --name kong-database \
               --network=kong-net \
               -p 5432:5432 \
               -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
               -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
               -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong" \
               postgres:9.6